# Good books on conic section.

Tags: reference-request, conic-sections

Can anybody suggest me good books for conics section.I want it for IIT-JEE mains and advanced and also for ISC. It should be *available in India* .

Comment: On a semi-related note, "Four Point Conics" is required viewing for all true conics enthusiasts.

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=JEf2Ax4EcL4

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The elements of coordinate geometry](http://archive.org/details/elementsofcoordi00lone) (1895) by    Sidney Luxton Loney

[A treatise on conic sections](http://archive.org/details/treatiseonconics00salmuoft)  by  Salmon, George, 1819-1904

[A Treatise On The Analytical Geometry](http://www.eknigu.org/info/M_Mathematics/MD_Geometry%20and%20topology/Casey%20J.%20Treatise%20on%20analytical%20geometry%20%282ed.,%201893%29%28KA%29%28600dpi%29%28T%29%28619s%29_MD_.djvu) (1893) by John Casey

An elementary treatise on [analytical geometry](http://archive.org/details/elementarytreati1893john) by Johnston

Comment: All these is under print now? And which one is the best?

Comment: Neer, if you are interested in Hard Copy, you can try : http://www.junglee.com/mn/search/junglee/ref=sr_st?keywords=The+Elements+Coordinate+Geometry+Loney&qid=1365666206&rh=k%3AThe+Elements+Coordinate+Geometry+Loney%2Cn%3A683840031&sort=price

Comment: @Neer, to me, Loney can be a good one to start with, find the link in my previous comment

Comment: Can't I get in college street?

Comment: @neer, if it's Kolkata, you can call the sellers. What is problem in Cash on delivery online?

Comment: @labbhattacharjee: the first one looks good for me even, but is there any access to it,nowadays? It is so old. +1

Comment: Yeah its kolkata. No problem in cash on delivery I used flipkart before for it.

Comment: @BabakS., It's available in many online sellers in India.  Find the link in my earlier comment. Loney is the best to me:)

Comment: Okay Loney is the way to go. I will try it.

Answer (score 4):

I think this one:

> Modern Calculus and Analytic Geometry by Richard A. Silverman

could be one of the references you are looking for. It is an old book, but believe me or not what I know about calculus is cause of this great book. There is a section in this book which contains:

1- Analytic Geometry in $\mathbb R^2$.

2- Analytic Geometry in $\mathbb R^3$.

I hope you can find it in **Great India**.

Comment: (+1) For the great suggestion and calling India 'great' .:)

Comment: @Inceptio: Who cannot call it Great. :-)

Comment: I want a book which is solely focused on conic section. I can use this for calculas too. Offtopic: What was that about "great India" ?

Comment: @Neer: Have you referred to Co-ordinate geometry by **S.L.Loney**?

Comment: S.L. Loney no I haven't tried that . Is it good I mean to have a deep knowledge about conics?

Comment: @BabakS.Ok I will search it and if you get some then please share it .And yes G.I is better :)

Comment: @Neer: Ok,my friend.

Comment: @BabakS.: What's G.I and G.B now?

Comment: B-Britain I-India and I will try loney then @Inceptio

Comment: @BabakS. does that book that you referred has all types of  calculas? And thanks.

Comment: @Neer: I can say that it has, but, as many books it cannot covered all types as you or me expected. It makes you solid in Math's basic and modern aspects.

Comment: No I want Intregation by parts ,substitution,differential equation and some application of derivatives. @BabakS.

Comment: @Neer: Yes it has, but what lab noted you I think are better for you. Take his suggestions.

Comment: Okay. But I want this book for calculas.

Answer (score 3):

Being a JEE aspirant, I may help you with two books I use for co-ordinate geometry
Ty out the book by Vikas gupta [Advanced problems in Co-ordinate Geometry](https://www.amazon.in/Advanced-Problems-Coordinate-Geometry-2018-2019/dp/9384934046)
This book is awesome and sometimes even surpasses the level of IIT-JEE Advanced examinations.
S L lonely is a good book to develop basics for co-ordinate geometry but for advanced preparation, you may try this book.
The solutions given at the back of the book also provide a good approach