# Why I can't find modern books on conic sections and analytical geometry?

Tags: geometry, reference-request

I want to learn analytical geometry but unfortunately I can't find any modern book on this subject.

On this site I found a question [Good books on conic section.](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358019/good-books-on-conic-section) But all the suggestions given is more than a century old. I tried two chapters from the two books suggested and I can't take it anymore.

My problems with old books are

1) They are difficult to read due to the language used.

2) The problems given are so cumbersome and provide no insight,.I don't hate hard problems but problems in old books are like "factor this 5 degree polynomial".

3) Not really a problem but the formatting is really bad in them.

My question is why there is no new books on this subject, new means after 1960s-70s, is there no mathematical interest in conic sections ? or just sales of these books are not enough to make profit ?

Comment: there's a ton of new books on the subject.

Comment: Google "Classification of quadrics" and take a peek at the sources and references.

Comment: Any intro book on algebraic geometry should discuss conic sections. The right suggestion depends background. What is your background?

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo Can you link me some ? I can't find any.

Comment: @AreaMan How much should I know ?

Comment: https://www.amazon.com/s/ref=nb_sb_noss_2?url=node%3D13884&field-keywords=analytic+geometry

Comment: @JorgeFernándezHidalgo I did not consider them good because I can preview them on amazon. Generally popular books have previews. Which one of them should I get ?

Comment: you can read them freely on libgen

Comment: The non-analytical study of conic sections was a mainstay of math education in schools in England and France at one time. In France, this ended in the 1960s and in England around the same time, I think. Most of the English books on this are pre-war, and the latest French ones are from the 1950s. In any case, since you asked about conic sections *and* analytic geometry, I assume this isn't what you're talking about. Analytic geometry is generally an important first-year university topic in Russia, so there have been many comprehensive books on analytic geometry written in Russian. Some of...

Comment: @user49640 Do you know any of them which are also in English ?

Comment: them have been translated into Western languages. In many cases, these textbooks have no exercises, because it's assumed you'll get a separate problem book. One example, which does contain a relatively small number of exercises, however, is *Analytical Geometry* by Pogorelov. It was written in 1978 and translated into English in 1980. Others include a book by Bugrov and Nikolsky, one by Efimov translated into Spanish, and one by Beklemichev translated into French (which I haven't seen).

Comment: @user49640 Oh nice but I can't find that book where I live. I am fine with no exercises if there are more popular books than one you suggested.

Comment: What languages can you read (that would have a considerable amount of math written in them)?

Comment: @user49640 I found [this](http://portal.tpu.ru/SHARED/k/KONVAL/Textbooks/Tab1/Konev-Linear_Algebra_Vector_Algebra_and_Analytical_Geome.pdf) while searching  for the books you suggested, any thoughts on it ?<br/> I can read only English.

Comment: That book seems much less comprehensive than most. Also, likely self-translated.

Comment: @user49640 Oh bad. Do you know other Russian books that are in English on this subject ?

Comment: If you read French (scientific French is not that hard for English speaking people !) there is an exceptional recent book "Géométrie analytique classique" by J.D. Eiden (http://www.aryanalibris.com/index.php?post/Eiden-Jean-Denis-Geometrie-analytique-classique). It uses a modern approach but with many many classical problems. I wish it will be translated in English.

Comment: @JeanMarie It looks to me as if Analytical geometry is not very modern thing to learn. How is geometry done these days ? to be clear I mean which geometry course does university students take ?

Comment: The modern presentation of the different branches of Analytic Geometry/Projective geometry/conic curves etc... is **centered on Linear Algebra** (and this you don't find in books edited before 1950).

Comment: @JeanMarie I am studying linear algebra. Do you know any modern book on geometry with linear algebra ?

Comment: Many books can be found online, especially at Library Genesis. A good book on linear algebra is the one by Kostrikin and Manin, *Linear Algebra and Geometry*. Pedoe's *Geometry: A Comprehensive Course* is a very wide-ranging course that adopts a mixed synthetic and analytic approach.

Comment: It depends of what you call Geometry. If it is a 2D/3D/4D geometry, I advise you to see and to work with people in vision, image sysnthesis. They have often very interesting questions. If you lean on the theorical side, you will find interest in "differential geometry", first for surfaces embedded into $\mathbb{R}^3$ and then into general manifolds.

Comment: @JeanMarie Oh I never heard of differential geometry. I think it is related to calculus.

Comment: Yes but differential geometry is also connected to linear algebra by many  of its aspects.

Comment: @JeanMarie Ok I will try that topic after finishing Linear algebra. I guess differential geometry requires multivariable calculus. Thanks for all the information, have a nice day.

Comment: Nice  day to you (nice night for me, 23:00 Central European Time...). What is your country ?

Comment: @JeanMarie Wales or UK whatever you like to say. I wrote have a nice day because I did not know where you live :). Good night then.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here are some English titles on this topic written in the last few decades.

- *Analytical Geometry*, Pogorelov (1978, English translation 1980)
- *Analytical Geometry*, Spain (1963)
- *Analytical Geometry*, Vaisman (1997)
- *Fundamentals of Linear Algebra and Analytical Geometry*, Bugrov and Nikolsky (1980, English translation 1982)
- *Lectures in Geometry, Semester I: Analytic Geometry*, Postnikov (1979, English translation 1982)

Comment: Is  [this](https://archive.org/details/AnalyticalGeometry) the second book ?

Comment: Yes, that's the one.

Comment: Ok, I will read this one. It is short, free and I can read it in 2-3 months. Thank you very much.

Comment: All of these can be found online. Compare with Vaisman's book to see if it suits you. Personally, I would prefer books that presented the material using vectors.

Comment: Can you give me a link to Vaisman's book ?

Comment: You seem to know a lot about such books that are not famous. how this is so ?

Comment: Before doing searches to answer this question, I only knew the books by Postnikov and Pogorelov and another one that hasn't been translated into English (by P.S. Alexandrov). I knew them because I have an interest in math education, and because I once read the one by Postnikov.

Comment: Actually, I also knew older books in French and English, but they didn't answer your question.

Comment: Thank you, I like the book by vaisman. I will read that first. Thank you have a nice day or Good night(Russia is big). Can I ping you in this question if I need help in any other book recommendations ?

Comment: I'm actually American. But I'm familiar with math books from Russia because they are often among the best. Yes, sure.

Answer (score 1):

At a certain point, maybe the 1960s, two separate courses were combined into one course: "Calculus and Analytic Geometry".

The calculus text I used back around 1970 had a discussion of conics.  In particular, rotation and translation of coordinates to put the conic in a canonical form.

But I guess over the time since then, such things have been reduced considerably (or even eliminated completely) from the course.  And perhaps the course is now called "Calculus" again.

Comment: So it is useless to learn conic sections ?

Comment: @123 Not useless - but not very often useful these days, so not in the standard curriculum. When you need it in a particular context you search for it and learn it. There are conic section questions on this site from folks doing just that.

Comment: @EthanBolker Why ? is the study of conic sections complete ?

Comment: In my college we have two distinct courses, calculus and analytic geometry.

Comment: @123 Pretty much, after 2,000+ years. There are occasional new uses for old (not very well known) results. That's when people search or ask.

Comment: @EthanBolker And what about analytical geometry ?

Answer (score 0):

I recommend looking at the following two books, the first published by MAA and the second published by AMS.

[**Conics**](http://www.maa.org/press/maa-reviews/conics) by Keith Kendig (2005)

[**Geometry of Conics**](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0821843230) by A. V. Akopyan and A. A. Zaslavsky (2007)

Regarding older books, this one is probably my favorite:

[**Elements of Analytical Geometry**](https://catalog.hathitrust.org/Record/000358096) by George Alexander Gibson and Peter Pinkerton (1911) [see [these comments](http://pballew.blogspot.com/2009/07/happy-phrase-that-didnt-stick.html)]