# Resources for some advanced and creative conic section problems

Tags: reference-request, self-learning, learning

Recently I have been studying conic -sections in my school . The problems given  in the course are good but I am looking for any resources where I can find new theorems and strategies to solve the problems of comics. I want a resource which can provide Olympiad-like geometric problems on conic sections. So please can anyone suggest any good resource for such problems?

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/358019/good-books-on-conic-section

Comment: Thank you very much,@mathxx.

Comment: @SoumyadipDas i suggest you try Vikas Gupta, Cengage and Arihant contain some great questions here and there (these books are by indian authors, just type in the titles and you should be able to find their pdfs online) (new theorems and methods can only be found by trying every variation and one can(mostly) not expect for a book that would cover every possible method)